# Quick Download HTML Source in C#

Tags: c#, html, download, httprequest, webclient

I am trying to download a HTML source code from a single website (https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription/) in C#.

The issue is that it takes 10 seconds to download a 30kb HTML page source. Internet connection is not an issue, as I am able to download 10Mb files in this program instantly.

The following has been executed both in a separate thread and in the main thread. It still takes 10-12 seconds to download.

---

### 1)

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), url))
        {
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }
```

---

### 2)

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        client.Proxy = null;
        response = client.DownloadString(url);
    }
```

---

### 3)

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
        response = client.DownloadString(url);
    }
```

---

### 4)

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;

using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        response = client.DownloadString(url);
    }
```

---

### 5)

```
var client = new WebClient()
response = client.DownloadString(url);
```

---

### 6)

```
var client = new WebClient()
client.DownloadFile(url, filepath);
```

---

### 7)

```
System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
myProxy.IsBypassed(new Uri(url));
myWebClient.Proxy = myProxy;
response = myWebClient.DownloadString(url);
```

---

### 8)

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

---

### 9)

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
myRequest.Method = "GET";
WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
myResponse.Close();
```

---

I want a faster way to do this in C#.

Any information or help you can provide is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you measure time?

Comment: I use the visual studios debugger. Also, I set a break point before and after this portion of the code and it tells me the milliseconds that has elapsed during the step.

Comment: Have You tried to open the webpage in your browser? Does it also take that long to load?

Comment: I have and it doesn’t not take that long. I have also used curl and it is instant. I have cleared the cache and cookies to make sure it’s not loading fast because it’s stored as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is dated, but I think I found the cause: I've encountered this at other sites. If you look at the response cookies, you will find one named `ak_bmsc`. That cookie shows that the site is running the Akamai Bot Manager. It offers bot protection, thus blocks requests that 'look' suspicious.

In order to get a quick response from the host, you need the right request settings. In this case:

- Headers:

  - `Host`: (their host data) `www.faa.gov`
  - `Accept`: (something like:) `*/*`
- Cookies:

  - `AkamaiEdge = true`

example:

```cs
class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        private static readonly string _url = "https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription/";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,_url))
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Host", "www.faa.gov");
                request.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
                request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "AkamaiEdge=true");
                Console.WriteLine(await _client.SendAsync(request));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
```

Takes 896 ms for me.

by the way, you shouldn't put `HttpClient` in a using block. I know it's disposable, but it's not designed to be disposed.

Comment: This works really well! I never even thought of a 'bot manager' being the issue. Thank you for this information. I am still fairly new to C# and learning the quirks behind it. I will refrain from putting `HttpClient` in a using block.

Answer (score 0):

This Question has stumped everyone I have asked. I have found a solution that I am going to stick with.

This solution does what I need it to do in 0.5 seconds on average. This will only work for windows from what I can tell. If the user does not have "CURL" I revert and go to the old way that takes 10 seconds to get what I need.

The solution creates a batch file in a temporary directory, calls that batch file to "CURL" the website, then output the result of CURL to a .txt file in the temp directory.

```
private static void CreateBatchFile() 
    {
        string filePath = $"{tempPath}\\tempBat.bat";
        string writeMe = "cd \"%temp%\\ProgramTempDir\"\n" +
            "curl \"https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription/\">FAA_NASR.txt";
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, writeMe);
    }

private static void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        int ExitCode;
        ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
        Process Process;
        ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + $"{tempPath}\\tempBat.bat");
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
        Process.WaitForExit();
        ExitCode = Process.ExitCode;
        Process.Close();
    }


private static void GetResponse()
    {
        string response;
        
        string url = "https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription/";

        CreateBatchFile();
        
        ExecuteCommand();

        if (File.Exists($"{tempPath}\\FAA_NASR.txt")  && File.ReadAllText($"{tempPath}\\FAA_NASR.txt").Length > 10)
        {
            response = File.ReadAllText($"{tempPath}\\FAA_NASR.txt");
        }
        else
        {
            // If we get here the user does not have Curl, OR Curl returned a file that is not longer than 10 Characters.
            using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                client.Proxy = null;
                response = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
        }
    }
```